# when log4j have a big bug,how to change it in Kettle8.3?

Tags: etl, kettle

My kettle is v8.3,log4j version is 1.2.14

[image: screenshot of libraries]

How to update log4j to 2.15?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question but I just want to say, 1.2.14 is not affected by the vulnerability

Comment: Your version isn't impacted by CVE-2021-44228 vulnerability (Log4Shell). Log4Shell impacts log4j versions 2.0-beta9 to 2.14.1. Version 2.15.0 seems to have denial of service vulnerability, according to https://sysdig.com/blog/exploit-detect-mitigate-log4j-cve/ and 2.16.0 is recommended.

Comment: Of course, being such an old version it probably has other vulnerabilities, so you will want to upgrade.  Also 2.15 has a vulnerability as well, so you will want to go to 2.16  https://www.zdnet.com/article/second-log4j-vulnerability-found-apache-log4j-2-16-0-released/

Comment: I know it , but our client want to update to 2.15,I put new jar file in it ,but tools can not open now.

Comment: I would suggest contacting https://support.pentaho.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the version of log4j that kettle uses is not vulnerable to this exploit, but it IS still vulnerable to old ones.

FYI - there is an active log4j2 branch on the public github and there will be an upgrade available eventually so you don't need to do it all yourself. https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/tree/log4j2

It is a cumbersome task to do on your own, but it is possible. You would need to replace all of the log4j maven dependencies with log4j2 and then refactor every class that imports log4j. Unfortunately there are renamed methods and classes so you will need to make a lot of changes.

If I were you I would follow that log4j2 github branch and either wait for it to be merged or start cherry-picking from it. If you aren't familiar with Git or Java you can just wait for Pentaho to release this update.

Answer (score 0):

Where I work we have had discussions with Hitachi (creator of Pentaho) regarding the fact that pentaho is dependent on log4j 1.x which has been end-of-lifed since 2015 and that log4j 1.x has known vulnerabilities that won't be fixed.

Hitachi has stated they are going to upgrade 8.3 and 9.2 Enterprise Edition to have log2j 2.17+ by 2/28/22. They will update Pentaho Community 9.x in the next major release scheduled for late May 2022. However, note they will not fix the 8.x version in community (ever) and so they will remain on log4j 1.x here.

So if you using pentaho community they are offering a fix in May for 9.2, but you are out of luck with pentaho community 8.2/8.3.

However, we have been able to successfully use the log4j2 bridge in pentaho 8.2 and 8.3 (it would also probably work with pentaho 9.x). The log4j2 bridge provides an extra jar that keeps the log4j 1 interfaces but behind the scenes calls log4j2. In the best case, it is a drop-in replacement for log4j 1.x.  However, in Pentaho the bridge does not work for log4j 2.17.1 and lower (RenderMap and LogLog class not found exceptions).

However, log4j 2.17.2-SNAPSHOT does work (I had to compile it from the current log4j sources) as the missing classes are now in the bridge.  Here is how it is done...

- With the log4j2 bridge you replace the following log4j 1.x jar: log4j-1.2.17.jar
- With the following log4j2 jars: log4j-api-2.17.2-SNAPSHOT.jar, log4j-1.2-api-2.17.2-SNAPSHOT.jar (bridge jar), log4j-core-2.17.2-SNAPSHOT.jar

log4j2 bridge links...

- General info: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-1.2-api/index.html
- Directions for using the log4j bridge: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html